# How do I call specific email notifications for Odoo v11

Tags: odoo-11

I have a menu item that calls the action of the Odoo email notifications. This menu item is:

```xml
<menuitem 
  name="Notification List" 
  id="menu_notification_lists" 
  parent="menu_container" 
  action="mail.action_view_mail_mail" 
  sequence="1"
/>
```

This element shows all notifications.

How can I filter so that only notifications that say `container` in the message are shown?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: <menuitem name="Notification List" id="menu_notification_lists" parent="menu_container" action="mail.action_view_mail_mail" sequence="1"/> BUT! this shows me a tree with all the notifications but I only need the ones that say container in the message

Answer (score 0):

Solved:the action server is called from the menu item, and the action server calls a function from the model that has a domain with the desired filter

```
<menuitem name="Notification List" id="id_menu_item" parent="menu_parent" action="id_action_server" sequence="1"/>

<record id="id_action_server" model="ir.actions.server">
        <field name="name">Mail_notification_container</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_reference" />
        <field name="state">code</field>
        <field name="code"> action=model.get_function()
        </field>
<record>

@api.multi
def get_function(self):
    return {
        "name": "Container notification",
        "type": "ir.actions.act_window",
        "res_model": "mail.mail",
        "views": [(False, "tree"),(False, "form")],
        "domain":['|',('//here the filter is placed by the body of the message')],
        "target":"custom",
        }
```